# Banking apps not working after flashing OxygenOS

Tags: custom-roms, android-10, troubleshooting, oxygenos

Today I clean flashed OxygenOS OB16 Crocus V2 (Android 10) using OrangeFox Recovery in my Redmi Note 5 pro (whyred).

And before this, i was using Pixel Experience Plus (Android 10) and before that stock MIUI

I never rooted my device as only unlocked bootloader was sufficient for flashing PE and OxygenOS.
And I never flashed Magisk or SuperSU.

All my banking apps were working fine in Pixel Experience but after flashing OxygenOS today 3 apps (U-mobile, DigiLocker, UBI rewardz) are telling me "This app does not support rooted/jailbroken devices"..... 1 (PayTM) displayed this message but let me in on my own risk while 1 (GooglePay) doesn't show anything.

What I already tried :
I tried different apps from playstore to check for root access and SafetyNet check....but every single one of them told me I didn't have root and passed SafetyNet check.

I don't know why they're not working in OxygenOS while all 5 worked in Pixel Experience !!

Any solution/suggestions are welcomed.
[image: Root Checker]
[image: SafetyNet Test]

Comment: Are you sure your device passes both SafetyNet attestation tests (basicIntegrity + ctsProfile)? By installing a custom ROM even without root the ctsProfile test should always fail because the system is different and the open bootloader.

Comment: Yes, I've used the most reputable apps in playstore. Root Checker by joeykrim and SafetyNet Test by Free Android Tools. Btw, never had a problem running these banking apps in Pixel Experience....which is a custom rom too.

Comment: Edit : I've added images for proof.

Comment: The correct way to proceed would be to contact the banks and open an issue for that problem. Unfortunately from a bank perspective a custom ROM is the same as a rooted device (it is not stock and hence manipulated). Therefore this way is most likely a waste of time. There must be something on this ROM that is common for rooted devices. Try what happens if there is an su binary or an app installed that has a package name similar to a root related app.